# Cannot access Objective-C singleton's array from Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I made an array in a singleton to write objects into it from multiple parts of my code. Here's how:

```
// in singleton.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// make globally accessible array
@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *imgArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imgArray;
+ (id)sharedManager;
@end

// in singleton.m
#import "singleton.h"
```

For my .m file :

```
@implementation MyManager

@synthesize imgArray;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.imgArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
    NSLog(@"initialized");
    return self;
}

@end
```

I can access my array called imgArray it from my objective C code. However, In swift I get an error when I do this:

```
let array  = MyManager.sharedManager()

array.imgArray.add("hello world") .    (!!!) Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'imgArray'
```

I can access `MyManager.sharedManager()`, but Why can't I access `imgArray` the same way as in objective C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare it as `instancetype` or `MyManager *`. E.g.

```
+ (MyManager *)sharedManager;
```

or

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager;
```

---

A couple of suggestions:

1. The Swift convention for singleton’s is to use a class property name of `shared`, not a class method of `sharedManager()`. When you declare it in Objective-C, you might want to explicitly say that it’s a class property:

   ```
   @property (class, readonly, strong) MyManager *sharedManager NS_SWIFT_NAME(shared);
   ```

   This won’t change any of the Objective-C behavior, but in Swift, you can just do:

   ```
   let manager = MyManager.shared
   manager.images.add(image)
   ```

   This results in more concise and idiomatic Swift code.
2. I’d suggest that you audit your Objective-C for nullability. I.e., confirm what can be `nil` and what can’t. Since both `imgArray` (which I might just call `images`) and `sharedManager` can never be `nil`, I would just use the `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`/`END` macros which tells the compiler “unless I tell you otherwise, assuming this property cannot be `nil`”:

   ```
   //  MyManager.h

   @import UIKit;

   NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

   @interface MyManager : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray <UIImage *> *images;
   @property (class, readonly, strong) MyManager *sharedManager NS_SWIFT_NAME(shared);

   @end

   NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
   ```

   By telling the compiler that these two cannot be `nil`, that means that you’ll have to do less unnecessary unwrapping of optionals in your Swift code.
3. As an aside, notice that I didn't declare an instance variable. (And if you did need one, I wouldn’t advise declaring it in the public interface.) Objective-C will now synthesize the ivars backing our properties automatically for us. (So my property `images` will have an ivar called `_images` that will be synthesized for me.) And you don’t need/want the `@synthesize` line, either:

   ```
   //  MyManager.m

   #import "MyManager.h"

   @implementation MyManager

   + (instancetype)sharedManager {
       static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
       static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
       dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
           sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
       });
       return sharedMyManager;
   }

   - (instancetype)init {
       if (self = [super init]) {
           self.images = [NSMutableArray new];
       }
       NSLog(@"initialized");
       return self;
   }

   @end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Change `+ (id)sharedManager;` to `+ (MyManager *)sharedManager;`. Otherwise Swift doesn't know what kind of object `sharedManager` is and it will assume it's `Any`.

Comment: Or `instancetype` instead of `id`, too.